# How does the SQL Server deal with the discrepancy between role's permission and user's permission

Tags: sql-server, authentication

If user A has a higher permission than the role's permission which he/she belongs to, which permission will SQL Server takes?

Comment: Permissions are replicated between logins and users.

Comment: A DENY will ALWAYS take precedence regardless of where it originated.

Comment: Both. The user has all the permissions granted to them (or denied to them) from the roles they belong to as well as those unique to the user. Roles are not "higher" or "lower" than the user's own account. Per Sean, deny takes precedence over grant (with the rare exception of a table-level deny not overriding a column-level grant, for hysterical reasons). Note that as a special case, object owners and sysadmins cannot be denied permission (or rather, that will be ignored).